# Create Comma Separated List In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013, worksheet-function

I have two workbooks that I need to pull data from workbook1, to workbook2.  The identifier to achieve such is `empID`  Now for each`empID` I need to show what location(s) they worked.  So sample data looks like this

**Workbook1**

empID.....Name....Address...City...State....Zip
1
2
3
4
5

**Workbook2**
empID.......locationworked
1      12

2  33

1  11

4  22

3  9

1  55

5  19

2  76

1  99

I have used this formula to return the data to a different cell for each `empID`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1))),"" )
```

But I want to create a Comma Separated list and put everything in one cell, like so

```
1   11,12,55,99
2   33,76
```

etc

Is there a way to modify the syntax so that a comma separated list is created like in my desired output?

Comment: If you have access to Excel 2016, you could use `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,TRANSPOSE(IF(Empl=A2,Location,"")))`, entered with **ctrl + shift + enter** in column C of Workbook 2 (assuming your data is in columns A & B; then filter to just show the unique Emp ID's, but not sure how to do it in 2013

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - unfortunately I do not have access to Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In workbook 2, I added this formula to column C

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,A2:$C$50,3,0)&","&B1,B1).
```

This assumes that your data goes as far down as row 50. Replace `$C$50` with whatever row is last in your spreadsheet.

If this is a variable list, use

```
=INDIRECT("A2:C"&MATCH(TRUE,D:D="",0),1)
```

in place of the

```
A2:$C$50
```

however don't forget to use Ctrl + Shift + Enter to set the formula to an array.

Next, copy this formula down all rows. The VLOOKUP will work up the sheet. Then you can reference this list from your report sheet (I believe in this case its Sheet 1) with a VLOOKUP. it will automatically pick the first instance of each employee ID which contains the csv list.

Comment: Excellent formula for this purpose.  I believe that the lower Bound `$C$50` can be any cell that is at least as long as the table. Your formula works equally well referencing `$C$5000` with only nine lines of data.  And if the results MUST be returned with locations in numeric order, he can merely sort the table beforehand -- ascending by ID; descending by location

Comment: Good call on the not requiring the array MATCH formula. The beauty of VLOOKUP, however, is how it doesn't even require a sort when referencing that table. It, with no AI as Lotus 123 was, indiscriminately grabs the first instance thus a sort on the source data will not yield any additional benefit (however it will make visually dissecting the source data a heck of a lot easier)

Comment: Your formula gives the location id's in reverse order.  As I wrote, the sort is useful if the OP wants the location id's in sorted order as he showed in his question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that whilst bad_neighbor's solution is quite accurate and reusable for future data changes, it is often preferable to avoid lookups where possible, and to store calculated results as values, since these aren't perfectly efficient and tend to slow down the sheet something awful given a larger quantity of data, for example when filtering / unfiltering. It's worse in older versions.

So, if this list formatting were part of a manual operation, and assuming the requirement is for each list item to be in ascending order (per the question's output), I'd do the following instead:

0. If workbook2's order is important, add an index of the rows (D1 := 1; D2 := D1 + 1; paste values).
1. Sort workbook2 by [A ascending, B descending], including index if present.
2. Apply this formula to column C - a fillup version of the lookup.

```
C1 := IF(A1=A2,C2&", "&B1,B1)
```

3. Copy-paste special values column C.
4. Lookup from workbook1 + copy-paste special values.
5. Optionally sort back according to original index (D) in workbook2.